# Auto Create Current Time in Time(0) fileld SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to auto generate current time in a field which is marked as time(0) data type with GetDate() is not working.

Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Tables has _columns_, not _fields_.

Comment: You are right but I came from ms-access thats why typed the same syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GETDATE()` returns a `Datetime` datatype where as your datatype is time.
Either change your datatype to be `Datetime` or convert to time like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(TIME(0),GETDATE())
```

Comment: So I can't keep separate column for time and separate column for date? with auto generation?

Comment: @Sixthsense - if you're wanting to record the date *and* time you *shouldn't* be storing them as separate columns. It's a *single* logical piece of data. It belongs in a *single* column.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the "default value" for the date field to `getdate()`

```
alter table Table_NAME add constraint Column_NAMEDefault default getdate() for 
Column_NAME;
```

Thanks

Comment: It's working for date data type.  But not working for Time(0) data type and I am not getting the time.  It shows Null only.

Comment: Try this query `alter table Table_NAME add constraint Column_NAMEDefault default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for 
Column_NAME;`

Comment: Whether timestamp can be used multiple times in the same table?

Comment: No,a table can only have one column of this type.